# KO3 Routing with directory

Tags: routes, kohana-3

Have a problem with creating route for my controller.

I'd like to organize controllers in directories and I put one controller into users directory. However I have no idea how to access it.

There's `127.0.0.1/login/index` and I want it to look like this `127.0.0.1/users/login`. I moved controller into users directory however have no idea how to force my route to work correctly.

Following route is not working:

```
Route::set('users', 'users(/<controller>(/<action>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'login',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Comment: why are you still using the routes when you don't need it from your setup? your controller is already in the `user` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route has a `directory` param, use it:

```
Route::set('users', 'users(/<controller>(/<action>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'users',
        'controller' => 'login',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Also you can pass directory as dynamic route param:

```
Route::set('users', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'login',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Here we dont need default directory value because its required. You can set range of values using regex (third arg in Route::set() method).

PS. I like short routes for account actions:

```
Route::set('users', '<action>', array('action' => '(login|logout|register)'))
        ->defaults(array(
          'controller' => 'account',
        ));
```

So, http://example.com/login and http://example.com/logout will work.

Comment: Great explanation! Now I understand KO3 routes, for the first time. Thanks!